# Angular2 Lazy loading - Cannot find module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a following problem. I'm using angular2 lazy loading and i've ran into 'cannot find module' error. Here is my folder structure:

[image]

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'app/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{
    path: 'app', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canLoad: [AuthGuard], children: [
        { path: 'home', loadChildren: 'home.module'},
    ]
},
{ path: 'authenticate', loadChildren: 'authenticate.module' },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES),
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And my HomeModule looks like this:

```
export const HOME_ROUTES: Routes = [
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(HOME_ROUTES)
],
declarations: [HomeComponent]
})
export default class HomeModule { }
```

Comment: are you using angular-cli ?

Comment: No - just webpack.

Comment: Ok I don't really know with webpack but when using angular-cli, my loadChildren must start from app : `app/...`.

Comment: Here is my folder structure - http://screenshot.sh/ovXL9WrdirQqM
tried changing it to `app/modules/home.module` - didn't help.

Comment: I did something similar and for you it would translate to `loadChildren: './home.module#HomeModule'` - This works for angular-cli + webpack as well.